# Phpmyadmin won't connect to mysql database on macOS (docker-compose.yml)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

The following code works on Windows 11, but not on some Intel-based macOS systems (in this case High Sierra).

```yaml
version: "3.3"

services:
    web:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        volumes:
            - ./app:/app
            - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        links:
            - php
        networks:
            - wmnet

    php:
        image: php:fpm
        volumes:
            - ./app:/app
        networks:
            - wmnet
        command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - |
                docker-php-ext-install mysqli
                php-fpm

    db:
        image: mysql:latest
        command:
            --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci 
            --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
            MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_DATABASE: wm
            MYSQL_USER: user1
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: user1
        networks:
            - wmnet

    phpmyadmin:
        depends_on:
            - db
        image: phpmyadmin
        links:
            - db
        ports:
            - 5502:80
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: db
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            PMA_USER: user1
            PMA_PASSWORD: user1 
        networks:
            - wmnet
networks:
    wmnet:
```

The concept here was to run everything through a docker-compose.yml to simplify debugging for inexperienced Docker users in local development. Now I'm getting to the point where I don't understand enough about docker, why the code suddenly runs on some systems and not on others.

A little additional information: The containers run without throwing any errors, Phpmyadmin only gets the error that it cannot find an SQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that you need to delete everything.
(In this case Docker Dekstop)

- Volumes
- Images
- Containers

After that it worked perfectly fine.